# Is it possible to find all the subviews that exist at a point on iphone?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, tap

I would like to be able to retrieve info on a tap, about all the different subviews that are placed in that tap spot.  For example, if there was a background, and in front of it was a game character,  I would like to be able to tap on that character, and it will retrieve the info saying that both the character and the background are in that tap spot.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    //retrieve info about what other subviews lie behind at this point
}
```

Comment: hitTest may help you...

Answer (score 4):

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
  {
   UITouch *touch=[touches anyObject];
   CGPoint p=[touch locationInView:self.view];
   NSLog(@"Coordiantes of Tap Point:(%f,%f)", p.x, p.y);

   NSArray *anArrayOfSubviews = [self.view subviews];
   NSMutableArray *requiredSubviewArray = [NSMutableArray array];

   for (UIView *aSubView in anArrayOfSubviews){
     if(CGRectContainsPoint(aSubView.frame, p)) {
        //aSubView is there at point 'p'
        [requiredSubviewArray addObject:aSubView];
     }
  }
// requiredSubviewArray contains all the Subviews at the Tap Point.
```

}

Answer (score 0):

try this.it maybe helpful to you..

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    //retrieve info about what other subviews lie behind at this point
   NSLog(@"subviews--%@",[self.view subviews]); //it prints all subviews as Array
    NSLog(@"superview--%@",[self.view superview]); //it prints superview of your view
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];  // here you get all subviews on ur touchpoint

if ([touch view] == imageView) {

    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView: self.view];

    imageView.center = location;

}

}

///  To check both views are in one spot, use this

// CGRectContainsRect() and CGRectIntersectsRect().
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this one..

You can get all subviews if you use [self.view subviews]. You can compare those views frames with touch location.

```
 -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    {
       CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.view];
       startX = touchLocation.x;
       startY = touchLocation.y;

        for (UIView *view in [self.view subviews]){
           //Here you can compare each view frame with touch location 
        }
    }
```